# C# Understanding why Bitwise OR is used in SSL Protocol assignment

Tags: c#, .net, enums, bitwise-operators, bitwise-or

Given the following C# **:

```
handler.SSLProtocol = SslProtocols.Tls13 | SslProtocols.Tls12;
```

Where `SSLProtocol` is the property being assigned.  `SslProtocols` is an Enum. And the pipe `|` is a bitwise OR.

I know what bitwise OR is, and that it will do the following for example: `101 | 100 = 101`.

But, my question is why write the code like this? i.e. why even use bitwise OR?

Why not just set the property like the following for example:

```
handler.SSLProtocol = SslProtocols.TlsX;
```

Or whatever the equivalent of `SslProtocols.Tls13 | SslProtocols.Tls12` equals using the bitwise or?

(*for the example I'm pretending here that `SslProtocols.Tls13 | SslProtocols.Tls1 = SslProtocols.TlsX`)

**This line of code was sent to me by a friend and i do not have access to the source to see the Enum or SSLProtocol property definition, but I'm guessing its probably `System.Net.SecurityProtocolType`

Comment: Like any enum, it is to help you choose the right value. You could, in fact, set the SSLProtocol to any integral value you want.

Comment: You need to lookup what the [Flags] attribute on an enum type does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are probably assuming something that is false:

```
enum MyEnum
{
    One = 1;
    Two = 2;
}

var three = (MyEnum)3; //is this legal?
```

Yes, it is, that will compile just fine. Its arguably a bad choice if `MyEnum` is not a bit field (`[Flags]` attribute), but its not enforced by the compiler. It probably would have been a good idea if the language had made a distinction between enums and flags because they are altogether different things but that train passed by a long time ago.

If on the other hand the `enum` is a bit field, then oring is a *must* because the enumeration options are not exlcusive (that is precisely the whole point of flags) and it wouldn't be very useful if you had to come up with every possible valid combination when defining your `enum` type:

```
[Flags]
enum AnimalTraits
{
     None         = 0
     Reptile      = 1 << 0,
     Mammal       = 1 << 1,
     Vertebrate   = 1 << 2,
     Invertebrate = 1 << 3,
     Amphybious   = 1 << 4,
     Acuatic      = 1 << 5,
     //etc.
}

var myAnimalFlags =  AnimalTraits.Invertebrate | 
                     AnimalTraits.Amphybious | 
                     AnimalTraits.Reptile
```

Now you have an enum value that has those three flags set which can be handy for filtering data, setting options in some UI, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried a c# fiddle of your Flags example and found that myAnimalFlags is set to Vertebrate, Acuatic which I find strange. Have a look at the final comment in this fiddle please. Where I ask is is set to Vertebrate, Acuatic because 2+5=7? If that is the case, then I find it counter intuitive to understand why you would set var myAnimalFlags like that. Have I done something wrong in the fiddle?      https://dotnetfiddle.net/H1M6qF

Comment: You can use the flag to test what bits are set. Imagine you recieve an animal with a certain flag value. You want know if its a mammal? Easy: `bool isMammal = (animalFlag & AnimalTraits.Mammal) == AnimalTraits;`. You want to know if its a reptile *and* amphybious? `bool isReptAndAmph = (animalFlag & (AnimalTraits.Reptile | AnimalTraits.Amphibious)) == AnimalTraits.Reptile | AnimalTraits.Amphibious;`, and so on. It can be confusing at first because the *ands* when you speak are the *ors* when you twiddle bits; *oring* a bit field is like adding "features"

Comment: Thanks. Just in reference to the example code, and my specific issue from the C# fiddle where myAnimalFlags is actually set to the value "Vertebrate, Acuatic". I think this is because the underlying enum values should be explicitly set to ints to the power of 2 in order to be able to correctly set myAnimalFlags to a list of enums like Invertebrate, Amphybious, Reptile.

Comment: @fourbeatcoder yes that is correct. I tipically set them in what I consider a readable way to convey that the underlying values are powers of two: `0, 1 << 0, 1 << 1, 1 << 2, 1 << 3`, etc.

Comment: @fourbeatcoder And sorry, yes, I omitted that important bit of info in my original answer. Edited accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for all of the details

Answer (score 0):

Given a flags enum with 8 enum items, with the bitwise OR you can express 2^8 = 256 configurations. With 32 options you can represent more than 4 billion combinations. So, without the OR you would have to define all possible enum options. Even come up with proper names would be challenging.

You can though combine the two approaches. If one or more flag combinations are common, you can define them as well as part of the enum items.

Comment: For info about FlagsAttribute see the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.flagsattribute?view=netcore-3.1.